# Getting initial number from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the initial number value of a string using jQuery/Javascript. Right now, the string I'm getting is:

```
  2 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>
```

I'm trying to take this string (which is stored in a variable, and take only the initial number from it. Normally, I would take only the first digit, but I'm want to make this flexible, so the number could be any digits in length (for example, "2" to "20,000,000"), so I know that just taking the first few digits doesn't work.

Does anyone out there have a solution? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, it's pretty hard to understand.

Comment: "20,000,000" including the commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = '2 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​';
var parts = str.split(' ');
alert(parts[0]);​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat. It'll stop when it meets an non numeric character.

```
parseFloat(mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is using regex `^\d+` if you want to grab just digits, or `^[\d,]+` if you allow commas:

```
var input = '2 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>';
var number = input.match(/^\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there could be commas in the number, and maybe a dot for decimals, and there is always a space afterwards, I would match using a regex like this...

```
var str = '2,000.33 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>'
var bits = str.match(/^[\d,\.]+/)

// alerts 2,000.33
alert(bits[0])

// to convert to string...
num = parseFloat(bits[0].replace(/,/g,''))

alert(num)
// alerts: 2000.33 (treated as number, not as string representation of number)
```

Comment: `parseInt('2,000.33')` is equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

If the number isn't comma-delimited:

```
var s   = '1234 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>',
    num = parseInt(s, 10);
```

If the number is comma-delimited:

```
var s   = '1,234 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>',
    num = parseInt(s.match(/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*/)[0].replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNum ( str ) {
    var result = '';
    var nums = str.match(/^(\d+|\,)*/);
    if(nums[0])
        result = parseFloat(nums[0].replace(/,/g,''));

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

`getNum ('2 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>')` 
Ouput: 2

`getNum ('20,000,000 <a href="user/usergroups.html?uname=Users@Users.com ">view</a>')` 
Output: 20000000